# Silverlight define clientaccesspolicy.xml path

Tags: xml, web-services, silverlight, ws-security

I'm using HttpWebRequest to call WebServices from another application, actually for security and rights measures I cannot place clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml in the root folder of my application.
Is there a way to specify the path ?
I would like something like this : http://myapplication/webservices/crossdomain.xml

Thanks for helping, I have been looking for answers but I cannot find anything about that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. This is a mandatory location. It's meant for the server owner to opt in to allow calls from other domains, which is why it's in the root for that owner to prove ownership of the server.